# Java Stream of Array

Tags: java-stream

I am writing a function to count the even numbers in an array. When I use Arrays.stream(numbers) to create a stream it works just fine. However when I try to create the stream by using Stream.of(numbers) i get the error message "The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int" in the filtering process.
What causes this and what is actually the problem here?

The first return statement results to the error,
The second return statement works just fine.

```
    public static long countEvenNumbers(int[] numbers) {
        return Stream.of(numbers).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0).count();
        // return Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0).count();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Stream#of` "[Returns a sequential ordered stream whose elements are the specified values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-)", and your "specified values" consist of a single element, namely an int[].

`Arrays.stream` however "[returns a sequential Stream with the specified array as its source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-)", ie the single elements in the array one by one.

BTW, in your case, you probably want `IntStream.of(numbers)`.

Comment: Why not stay with `Arrays.stream(…)` for an existing array, which works regardless of whether you have an `int[]`, `long[]`, `double[]`, or object array…